# Search Numbers in Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

As you may know, in Eclipse, we could search a text, which could be a field name or a method name, within a project or work-space, by using File Search. The results would be all the places that the text in question appears. Now, the issue is, I need to search for a number, i.e., 12. For example, number 12 has been used as a flag indicator in many places (in different java files) in a project, and I would like to find out all the places that this number is used. Is there a way to do this? I have tried to do the search in the same way as searching key word (File Search), but it did not work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Define *did not work*.

Comment: select your search string\number and then press `ctrl+alt+g`

Comment: What you described *should* work. The *File search* tab in the *Search* dialog is a pure textual search, equivalent to a `grep`. On a side note, you [**shouldn't be using magic numbers**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/2685386)

Comment: If you liked any post, feel free to accept it as correct answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to use the text search for numbers.

```
Search => File
Containing text: 12
File name patterns: Adjust to *.java
Scope: Workspace - for full search
```

Should work like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok..

1. Type `12` in any file.
2. select the text (12)
3. goto Search --> Text --> Project

Answer (score 0):

Press `CTRL+H`- A menu pops up.

Select the `customize` button and in that check `File Search field`

Then in the  `File Search` tab define as follow -

In `Containing Text Field` - type whatever you want to search.

In `File name patterns field` - provide the files you want to search e.g- `*.java` will search for all `java` files.

Finally Hit `search`. Shall give you the files containing the search number